# javascript function ".map" doesn't read a data array. It just throws an error that the element is NULL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, json, mongodb

When using the `.map` method on the data variable I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')".

From what I can tell, for some reason my data from the .json file is being passed as objects and not as an array.

## My function file

```
import React from 'react'
import SearchBar from '../../components/SearchBar/SearchBar'
import './Properties.css'
import useProperties from '../../hooks/useProperties'
import { PuffLoader } from 'react-spinners'
import PropertyCard from '../../components/PropertyCard/PropertyCard'

const Properties = () => {
  const { data, isError, isLoading } = useProperties()
  if (isError) {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <span>Error while fetching data</span>
      </div>
    )
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper flexCenter" style={{ height: "60vh" }}>
        <PuffLoader height="80" width="80" radius={1} color='#4066ff' aria-label='puff-loading' />
      </div>
    )
  }
  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="flexColCenter paddings innerWidth properties-container">
        <SearchBar />
        <div className="paddings flexCenter properties">
          {

            data.map((card, i) => (<PropertyCard card={card} key={i} />))

          }
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Properties
```

## Example my .json file

```json
[
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "64392d39dfd90fb29e464fb7" },
    "title": "Sunny Meadow Cottage",
    "description": "Massive opportunity to build your dream home at the base of Mummy Mountain in the 3 C's school district. Home is currently updated and very livable if your plans are to build at a later date.* Bonus * to live hillside without hillside restrictions in the town of PV. Run don't walk to capture this needle in a hay stack.",
    "price": 6000,
    "address": "Street 1",
    "city": "Chicago",
    "country": "US",
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/7031406/pexels-photo-7031406.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
    "userEmail": "mukhtarhamza294@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:38:48.762Z" },
    "updatedAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:38:48.762Z" },
    "facilities": { "bathrooms": "2", "parking": "1", "bedrooms": "5" }
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "64392e0bdfd90fb29e464fbc" },
    "title": "Coastal Breeze Villa",
    "description": "Massive opportunity to build your dream home at the base of Mummy Mountain in the 3 C's school district. Home is currently updated and very livable if your plans are to build at a later date.* Bonus * to live hillside without hillside restrictions in the town of PV. Run don't walk to capture this needle in a hay stack.",
    "price": 8000,
    "address": "Street 2",
    "city": "Multan",
    "country": "Pakistan",
    "image": "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-84l-BoUL090/VTDHcQzSTNI/AAAAAAAAuHI/Khftta_CF5E/s1920/wow-home-design.jpg",
    "facilities": { "bathrooms": "5", "parking": "1", "bedrooms": "4" },
    "userEmail": "mukhtarhamza294@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:42:19.231Z" },
    "updatedAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T10:42:19.231Z" }
  },
  {
    "_id": { "$oid": "6439001c74446601d6fce96d" },
    "title": "Citralan Puri Serang",
    "description": "Massive opportunity to build your dream home at the base of Mummy Mountain in the 3 C's school district. Home is currently updated and very livable if your plans are to build at a later date.* Bonus * to live hillside without hillside restrictions in the town of PV. Run don't walk to capture this needle in a hay stack.",
    "price": 3000,
    "address": "Street 3",
    "city": "California",
    "country": "US",
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/323780/pexels-photo-323780.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1",
    "userEmail": "mukhtarhamza294@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T07:26:20.051Z" },
    "updatedAt": { "$date": "2023-04-14T07:26:20.051Z" },
    "facilities": { "bathrooms": "3", "parking": "1", "bedrooms": "2" }
  }
]
```

I added a check to see if my date is an array:

```html
 <div className="paddings flexCenter properties">
        {
        data && Array.isArray(data) ? (
          data.map((card, i) => (<PropertyCard card={card} key={i} />))
        ) : (
          <p>No data available</p>
        )
      }
        </div>
```

## useProperties

```
import React from 'react'
import { useQuery } from 'react-query'
import { getAllProperties } from '../utils/api'

const useProperties = () => {

    const { data, isLoading, isError, refetch } = useQuery(
        "allProperties", getAllProperties, { refetchOnWindowFocus: false }
    )

    return (
        data, isError, isLoading, refetch
    )
}

export default useProperties
```

The answer was quite obvious:

Comment: Can you share your code for useProperties?

Comment: What is happening here is `data` initially is `undefined` because I'm assuming there is an async request that happens to load... And then after the data has loaded you then have the results in an array like you are seeing. This is a timing issue from loading data though. Your proposed solution is fine, another way you can do it is to default assign for undefined cases. `const { data = [], isError, isLoading } = useProperties()`. Or better yet use `??` and coalesce a default value for nullish cases that aren't `undefined` :)

Comment: will be able to give correct solution if you share the code of useProperties

Comment: @JasonMing Already added

Comment: @JohnRuddell I tried, it didn't help

Comment: @SravanKumar Already added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom hooks can return primitive values, objects, arrays or functions. The return type of custom hook was wrong in your code.
Please update `useProperties` like this.

```
const useProperties = () => {

    const { data, isLoading, isError, refetch } = useQuery(
        "allProperties", getAllProperties, { refetchOnWindowFocus: false }
    )

    return {
        data, isError, isLoading, refetch
    }
}
```